# Avoiding split CSV records in buffered reads?

Tags: csv, go

I've been having some oom issues with a little program I made to parse CSV and load to DB and decided to read files with a buffer (some CSV can be in the order of hundreds of MB and the server does not have a lot or memory to accomodate it all).

Because I'm working in "chunks", how can I prevent a record to be split between them? IE, the last record of chunk1 may be, or may be not complete, and the rest of it becomes a part of the first record in chunk2.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
func insertData(args []string, csvFile *os.File, tableToInsert IndexRecord) {
    log.Printf("Table %v.%v found. Inserting data in database. Batches of %v",
        tableToInsert.Schema, tableToInsert.Name, args[10])
    buffer := make([]byte, 2048000)
    for {
        _, err := csvFile.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            _, csvRecords := ParseCSVBytes(&buffer)
            batch, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[10])
            InsertRecords(tableToInsert, csvRecords, batch)
            if err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Instead of manual chunking, use a buffered reader and read line  by line.

Comment: Use a [csv Reader](https://godoc.org/encoding/csv#Reader) to [read a record at a time](https://godoc.org/encoding/csv#Reader.Read) from the file.

Comment: But world mean a lot of disk access.

Comment: The csv Reader uses [buffered i/o](https://godoc.org/bufio) when reading from the underlying reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [csv reader](https://godoc.org/encoding/csv#Reader).  It handles the buffered reads for you.

```
func insertData(args []string, csvFile *os.File, tableToInsert IndexRecord) {
    r := csv.NewReader()
    for {
        record, err := r.Read(csvFile)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err) // handle error as appropriate
        }
        InsertRecord(tableToInsert, record)
    }
}
```